# NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1 ng serve not working

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am trying to use the persistent build cache feature provided by angular but look like its not working for me, I am trying the below command

```
NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1 ng serve
```

It always returns below error

**'NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.**

I am using angular cli version 12.2.15. I am not sure what I am missing. Below is my packages.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.1100.2",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.15",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^12.2.15",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^4.9.10",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.1",
    "@webcomponents/shadydom": "^1.9.0",
    "acorn": "^8.0.4",
    "angular-chart.js": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-file-uploader": "7.0.3",
    "angular-mydatepicker": "^0.10.2",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-split": "4.0.0",
    "angular2-datetimepicker": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2-text-mask": "9.0.0",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "ckeditor": "4.12.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "events": "^3.2.0",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "first": "0.0.3",
    "fullcalendar": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "fullcalendar-scheduler": "^4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^8.2.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.1",
    "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "mdn-polyfills": "^5.20.0",
    "moment-mini-ts": "^2.20.1",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.9",
    "ng2-date-picker": "11.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "6.2.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.6",
    "ng9-password-strength-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "6.2.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-countdown": "11.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.5.2",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-fullcalendar": "^5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "ngx-hm-sortable": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-img-cropper": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "11.1.4",
    "ngx-mega-simple-drag-drop-list": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.4.4",
    "ngx-sortable": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-sortablejs": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.3.200",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.3",
    "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.4",
    "sortablejs": "^1.12.0",
    "ts-deferred": "^1.0.4",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
```

here is a snapshot when I am checking my package version using **ng v** command

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be using Windows `cmd` to run the command, and hence you are getting the error.

The command:

```js
NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1 ng serve
```

is for Unix-like systems and won't work within Windows `cmd`.

You can use any of the below methods to make it work:

- First set environment variable and then run the command

```js
// 1st command to set the environment variable
set NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1

// 2nd command
ng serve
```

- Run both commands within single step

```js
set NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1&&ng serve
```

- Add the below command within package.json scripts and then run `npm start`

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "set NG_PERSISTENT_BUILD_CACHE=1&&ng serve",
  ...
}
```

**PS:** In all the above methods the environment variable value is set for the `cmd` session in which we run the command. If you want to set the environment variable globally, then that can be achieved by adding System variables within Environment Variables dialog. (System Properties -> Environment Variables -> System variables).

Comment: Thank you so much @Siddhant.You really saved my day. I wasted the whole day on this one. I am really surprised they never mentioned anywhere in the document that this will only work for UNIX-like systems but not for Windows. again thank you so much.It's working perfectly fine